# OBIEE: Line graphs from pivot table

Tags: sql-server, graph, obiee

I am very new to the Oracle Business Intelligence tool which uses SQL. I have filtered my data and organized it into a pivot table. The pivot table returns values like this:

```
Week    Value
08      100.00
11      100.00
13      100.00
14      89.29
15      99.76
16      90.67
17      90.24
```

There are more values, but as you can see the lowest values are in the mid to high 80s. Yet my graph is showing strange negative values:

[image]

**So my question is how to assure what values are being plotted in the graph are the values in my pivot table?** Everything looks fine in the "Layout" section but I am curious if there is a way to assure the values are displayed in the graph *exactly* as they are in the pivot table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created separate chart and pivot views then there's a good chance the figures in them could be different, depending on how you've built them.

If you create the chart within the pivot view, then the values charted will be those from the pivot table.
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to multiple pivot tables within one analysis? I have been trying New View > Pivot Table but am unable to get a new view to start

Comment: @a.powell Yes, you can have as many as you like I believe. Check your Views pane in the bottom left of the analysis, it may be they are being created but not added to the compound view?